# passing arguments to _beginthread() -- whats wrong?

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, arguments

I have this code and I am not getting the expected results... whats wrong?

```
typedef struct {
   int data1;
   int data2;
}t;

void foo(int a, int b) {

   Handle handle;
   t arg;
   arg.data1 = a;
   arg.data2 = b;
   handle = (HANDLE) _beginthread( myFunc, 0, (void*) &arg);
}

void myFunc(void *param) {
   t *args = (t*) param;
   int x = args->data1;
   int y = args->data2;
   printf("x=%d, y=%d\n", x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arg` is a local variable defined in `foo` - it would be destroyed as soon as that function ends, but `myFunc` which is running in another thread would still be trying to access it. You should allocate `arg` on the heap and destroy it in the thread after you are done.

```
void foo(int a, int b) {
   HANDLE handle;
   t *arg;
   arg = (t *)malloc(sizeof(t));
   arg->data1 = a;
   arg->data2 = b;
   handle = (HANDLE) _beginthread( myFunc, 0, (void*) arg);
}

void myFunc(void *param) {
   t *args = (t*) param;
   int x = args->data1;
   int y = args->data2;
   printf("x=%d, y=%d\n", x, y);
   free(args);
}
```

Also note that `HANDLE` should be all caps.

Comment: @ Casablanca , I think you made a typo.

handle = (HANDLE) _beginthread( myFunc, 0, (void*) args); /// its arg

Thanks
Alok.kr.

Comment: Shouldn't you declare stacksize as non-zero?

Comment: @bobobobo: A zero stack-size means the thread will get the default stack size.

Answer (score 0):

your arg variable is a local variable in your function foo, so it will not be available in the memory after the function ends.

SO you can do two things:

1.define your arg variable globally.

```
typedef struct {
   int data1;
   int data2;
}t;
t arg;
```

or you can also allocate the memory for arg on help,as casablanca has explained.

Thanks
*Alok.Kr.*